# Show/disable button with PHP and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

How would I go about disabling/enabling a button when the UNIX timestamp reaches <= 0.

I use AJAX to continuously call a .php-file every 250ms. In this .php-file I check if its been 90 seconds since last action was taken by comparing the time (in UNIX) now to the last time I pressed the button (using a MySQL database).

The comparison is done by subtracting time it was pressed to the time now.

I would like to enable the button when the UNIX timestamp when there's less than or equal to 0 seconds since the button was last pressed.

Having a cooperation between PHP and JavaScript is a challenge, I know that, but I also know there are ways to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with jquery depending on what the script is about. Rather than calling ajax, you could assign an attribute to the time and then using a jquery setInterval function decrease the time by 1 second and then check whether the time is less than 0 or not?
Example:

> HTML:

```
<input type='submit' id='button' name='button' data-time='(using php, put the seconds in here' />
```

> Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var timer = setInterval(function() {
var current = $("#button").data('time');
// get the current value of the time in seconds
var newtime = current - 1;
if (newtime <= 0) {
// time is less than or equal to 0
// so disable the button and stop the interval function
$("#button").prop('disabled', true);
clearInterval(timer);
} else {
// timer is still above 0 seconds so decrease it
$("#button").data('time', newtime);
}
}, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use javascript or jQuery to disable the button by changing it's `disabled` property.  You can use javascript to change it back also.

Example:  `document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled = true;`

Read more here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_pushbutton_disabled.asp